# Concating 2 input fields values in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have  an `form` with 3 input fields called `Name` ,`hours` & `minutes`.While performing **POST** operation i am concatinating `hours` and `minutes` to variable called `duration`. Then i am sending to the **api**
The exact JSON looks like this:

```
[
 {
  "displayName": "Car Rent",
  "duartion": "06:27:00",
 },
 {
  "displayName": "Bike Rent",
  "duartion": "10:15:00",
 },
 {
  "displayName": "Texi Rent",
  "duartion": "05:30:00",
  },
]
```

But,When i concat `hours` and `minutes` and **POST**, The JSON string like this:

```
  [ 
   {
    "id": "7249328f-fad4-4548-87b0-947e99b57892",
     "displayName": "Car Rent",
    "duration": "1020.00:00:00",   <===============
   },
   {
    "id": "7e39f9302-77b3-4c52-a858-adb67651ce86",
     "displayName": "Taxi Rent",
    "duration": "0510.00:00:00",   <===============
   }
  ]
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-xs7ob6?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: I want store as per the 1st **JSON**

Comment: You mean `this.someWork.duration = parseInt(this.addForm.value.hours) + ":" + parseInt(this.addForm.value.minutes) + ":"+ "00";`?

Comment: This is the exact format i was looking for..Thank you @Justcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.someWork.duration = `${this.addForm.value.hours}:${this.addForm.value.minutes}`;
```